# Trying to update a text field from a picklist value for 1 or more items selected as checkbox = true

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to update the field `Which_colour__c` from the `value` selected in the `handleChange` function, but am a little stuck.
Code below:

Controller:

```apex
public class getWWUNorth {
    @AuraEnabled
    Public static List<Patch_Book__c> fetchpb(){
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Patch__c,Traffic_Light_Status__c, Which_Colour__c,Area__c,Postal_Outcode__c,Region__c 
                FROM Patch_Book__c 
                WHERE Region__c ='North' AND Area__c = 'WWU'];
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void updateRecord(List <String> lstRecordId) {
        List<Patch_Book__c> lstUpdate = new List <Patch_Book__c>();
        for(Patch_Book__c pb : [SELECT Id, Name, Patch__c,Which_Colour__c,Traffic_Light_Status__c, Area__c,Postal_Outcode__c,Region__c FROM Patch_Book__c WHERE Id IN : lstRecordId]){
            pb.Which_Colour__c = 'green';
            lstUpdate.add(pb);
        }
        
        if(lstUpdate.size() > 0){
            update lstUpdate;
        }
    }      
}
```

Component:

```html
<aura:component controller="getWWUNorth" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
   <aura:attribute name="statusOptions" type="List" default="[]"/>
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this }" action="{! c.loadOptions }"/>
   <lightning:combobox aura:id="selectItem" name="status" label="Status"
                      placeholder="Choose Colour"
                      value="new"
                      onchange="{!c.handleChange}"
                      options="{!v.statusOptions}"/>
   <aura:attribute name="pbList" type="List" default="['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']" />
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.loadpbs}"/>
   <aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.loadpbs}" />
   <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-end"> 
      <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.updateFields}">Update Colour</button>
   </div>
   <lightning:card title="Wales and West North Area">
      <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
         <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer slds-size--1-of-8 slds-p-horizontal_x-small">
            <thead>
               <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
                  <th style="width:3.25rem;" class="slds-text-align--right">
                     <div class="slds-form-element">
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                           <label class="slds-checkbox">
                              <!--header checkbox for select all-->
                              <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="box3" change="{!c.selectAll}"/>
                              <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
                              <span class="slds-form-element__label text"></span>
                           </label>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                     <span class="slds-truncate">Postcode</span>      
                  </th>
                  <th>
                     <span class="slds-truncate">Which colour</span>
                  </th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <aura:iteration items="{!v.pbList}" var="pb">
                  <tr>
                     <td scope="row" class="slds-text-align--right" style="width:3.25rem;">
                        <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-8 slds-p-horizontal_x-small">
                           <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                              <label class="slds-checkbox">
                                 <ui:inputCheckbox text="{!pb.Id}" aura:id="boxPack" value=""/>
                                 <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
                                 <span class="slds-form-element__label text"></span>
                              </label>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                     <td scope="row">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!pb.Postal_Outcode__c}">{!pb.Postal_Outcode__c}</div>
                     </td>
                     <td scope="row">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!pb.Which_colour__c}">{!pb.Which_colour__c}</div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </aura:iteration>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

JS:

```javascript
({
    loadpbs: function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get('c.fetchpb');
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set('v.pbList', response.getReturnValue());
                component.find("box3").set("v.value", false);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    
    selectAll: function(component, event, helper) {
        var selectedHeaderCheck = event.getSource().get("v.value");
        var getAllId = component.find("boxPack"); 
        if(! Array.isArray(getAllId)){
            if(selectedHeaderCheck == true){ 
                component.find("boxPack").set("v.value", true);    
            }else{
                component.find("boxPack").set("v.value", false);
            }
        }else{
            // check if select all (header checkbox) is true then true all checkboxes on table in a for loop  
            // and set the all selected checkbox length in selectedCount attribute.
            // if value is false then make all checkboxes false in else part with play for loop 
            // and select count as 0
            if (selectedHeaderCheck == true) {
                for (var i = 0; i < getAllId.length; i++) {
                    component.find("boxPack")[i].set("v.value", true);
                }
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < getAllId.length; i++) {
                    component.find("boxPack")[i].set("v.value", false);
                }
            } 
        }  
    },
  
    loadOptions: function (component, event, helper) {
        var options = [
            { value: 'Red', label: 'Red' },
            { value: 'green', label: 'Green' },
            { value: 'Amber', label: 'Amber' }
        ];
        component.set("v.statusOptions", options);
    },
    handleChange: function (cmp, event) {
        // Get the string of the "value" attribute on the selected option
        var selectedOptionValue = event.getParam("value");
        alert("Option selected with value: '" + selectedOptionValue + "'");
    },
    
    updateFields: function(component, event, helper) {
        var updateId = [];
        var getAllId = component.find("boxPack");
        
        if(! Array.isArray(getAllId)){
            if (getAllId.get("v.value") == true) {
                updateId.push(getAllId.get("v.text"));
            }
        }else{        
            for (var i = 0; i < getAllId.length; i++) {
                if (getAllId[i].get("v.value") == true) {
                    updateId.push(getAllId[i].get("v.text"));
                }
            }
        } 
        
        var action = component.get('c.updateRecord');
        action.setParams({
            "lstRecordId": updateId
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                console.log(state);
                $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
})
```